# How to get a value of input[type=checkbox] using jQuery and pretty checkbox plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have this code on the HTML part:

```
<div class="clearfix prettycheckbox labelright blue">
   <input class="car_type" type="checkbox" value="16" name="" style="display: none;">
   <a class="" href="#"></a>
   <label for="undefined"></label>
</div>
```

And What I have so far in JS:

```
$('.prettycheckbox').click(function () {
      var clickedValue = $(this).//here I need some code to get the input before
      alert('Value is ' + clickedValue);
});
```

So, I basically need to get the value (16; value="16") of the input field inside of div.prettycheckbox that was clicked.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.prettycheckbox').click(function () {
      var clickedValue = $(this).find(':checkbox').val();
      alert('Value is ' + clickedValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickedValue = $(this).children('.car_type:checkbox').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$('.prettycheckbox').click(function () {
      var clickedValue = $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').val()
      alert('Value is ' + clickedValue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').val();
```